# Select Top 1 with multiple Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table in SQL Server 2016 (I believe it was originally from 2008 or 2012 and it's just moved to the 2016 cluster) with patient events, the type of event, and the severity of the event (called a grade). There are several instances where the same patient will have multiple events occur but with varying grades. So, a sample of data will look something like this:

```
| Pt_id | Event          | Grade |
+-------+----------------+-------+
| 01    | Pain           | 2     |
| 01    | Pain           | 4     |
| 01    | Nausea         | 2     |
| 02    | Headache       | 2     |
| 02    | Headache       | 3     |
| 03    | Blurred Vision | 3     |
| 03    | Blurred Vision | 4     |
| 03    | Bluured Vision | 3     |
| 03    | Nausea         | 4     |
| 03    | Nausea         | 2     |
```

I'm trying to get the highest grade for each of the different events per patient. My desired output for that data would be as follows:

```
| Pt_id | Event          | Grade |
+-------+----------------+-------+
| 01    | Pain           | 4     |
| 01    | Nausea         | 2     |
| 02    | Headache       | 3     |
| 03    | Blurred Vision | 4     |
| 03    | Nausea         | 4     |
```

I've tried using the the Top 1 incorporated into the query, the ROW_Number, Partition, and everything else Google has thrown at me but I get either too restricted of results (I'm getting around 30 rows but I actually went through the excel (I'm trying to do some QA here) and I should have just under 400 rows. I think that when I do these functions I'm missing something and it's grouping either all Pt_ids and just picking 1 row for all the Events for that Pt_id or it's doing that with the Event - and no matter what I try it won't give me one row per patient, per event, with the highest grade for that event and patient.

Although I've used SQL throughout the years, it's never been my primary function so  your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn’t this just group by patient and event, max of grade?

Comment: Hard to tell why your previous attempts didn't work when you don't post the code for them.

Comment: Apologies - the craziness that was my frustration with this Friday/This morning made me go through and remove most of my attempts as I would try 5, get management studio completely a mess, and clear it to start over. Yogesh Sharma got me figured out though - I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this enough with use of `GROUP BY` with `MAX()`  ?

```
SELECT Pt_id, Event, MAX(Grade)
FROM table t
GROUP BY Pt_id, Event;
```

If the table has more column other than only 3 columns, then use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `TIES` clause :

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
FROM table t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pt_id, Event ORDER BY Grade DESC);
```

Comment: There we go. I don't know if it was the 10 hour day on Friday, the crazy weekend, or something in between but it appears I just had some of the syntax incorrect with the ROW_NUMBER function. This appears to be giving me exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number` window function

```
   with cte as
    (
    select *,
    row_number() over(partition by Pt_id ,Event by order by Grade desc) rn 
    from your_table
    )select * from cte where rn=1
```

You have to use `order by Grade desc`for getting max value